# Creating an animated graphics overlay with Python

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, overlay, xorg

I'd like to hear the best means for displaying graphics that move on-screen as an overlay with Python.  The intended initial platform is Linux.  I've worked up some small demos using PyQt using frameless windows and looping and updating their location on screen.  This works, but I have a feeling it is not the ideal solution.

The end result is an activity indicator that would show more objects swarming in an upward direction as activity increased.  That would result in spawning perhaps a hundred windows in a go and that is why I think my PyQt demo is not optimal.

I'm open to any suggestions since this will be an open project and installing obscure modules is a non-issue.

Comment: This perhaps doesn't address your question, but have you looked into transparency? Is there any reason you can't have one transparent window with several partially transparent sprites being drawn in it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'd like it to function as an object you can never interact with, and the space I'd like it to occupy could interfere with scroll bars, etc. In practice perhaps that is the best solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are examples for making transparent / unclickable windows [in java](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) and [in javascript](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/). Here are [a couple](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq16-background.html) of [transparency related](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/1107) posts for QT.

Comment: I decided to go with a single frameless window using MNGs for animation. Thank you.